# Why is conversion constructor called in absense of assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Today my question is why is a constructor called in absence of a user provided assignment operator? I know the difference between constructor and assignment operator in relation to the `=` symbol. If an object did not exist previously before that line, the constructor is implicitly called.

`std::string name = "Bjarne";  // implicit constructor`

If an object already existed previously before that line, then assignment operator is called.

```
std::string name;
name = "Bjarne";   // assignment operator
```

Now I have a `class Number` here, which is a tagged union. It is simply a number, means either an `int` or a `float`. I have multiple conversion constructors defined which make it easy for the user to assign values to the `Number` implicitly. I expect them to be called in such situation:

`Number num1 = 8;`

In order to know for sure which constructor is called when, I put print statements in the bodies of the constructors.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;


/* Unions can be anonymous (unnamed).
 * This form is used when nesting a union inside a struct or class that contains an extra data member
 * to indicate what the union contains.
 * This arrangement is called a tagged union (or managed union).
 * It can be used as a "polymorphic" class which can be several things at once, for example to create an array
 * of different data types.
 */

class Number {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Number& num);
  public:
    Number(int i = 0) : DATA_TYPE(INTEGER), i(i) { cerr << "Number(" << i << ")\n"; }

    Number(unsigned int u) : DATA_TYPE(INTEGER), i(static_cast<int>(u)) { cerr << "Number((signed) " << i << ")\n"; }

    Number(float f) : DATA_TYPE(FLOAT), f(f) { cerr << "Number(" << f << ")\n"; }

    Number(double d) : DATA_TYPE(FLOAT), f(static_cast<float>(d)) { cerr << "Number((float) " << f << ")\n"; }    

    Number(const Number& rhs) : DATA_TYPE(rhs.DATA_TYPE), i(rhs.i) { cerr << "Number((Number) " << *this << ")\n"; }
  private:
        enum data_type { INTEGER, FLOAT } DATA_TYPE;

    union {
        int i;
        float f;
    };
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Number& num)
{
    switch (num.DATA_TYPE) {
        case Number::INTEGER:
      cout << num.i;
          break;
        case Number::FLOAT:
      cout << num.f;
          break;
    default:
      cout << 0;
      break;
    }

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    Number num1 = 5;  // conversion constructor
    cout << num1 << endl;
    num1 = 12.5;
    cout << num1 << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run this code it produces unexpected output for me:

```
Number(5)
5
Number((float) 12.5)
12.5
```

I see that when `Number num1` is initialized, the constructor taking an `int` as a parameter is called. Then I print the value of `num1`. Then on the next line it seems that the constructor taking a `double` as a parameter is called. This is strange. Before that line, `num1` already existed as an object. So it should logically call assignment operator instead. No assignment operator was defined by me instead, so I assume that the assignment operator generated by the compiler will be called.

I want to know, in the absence of a user provided assignment operator, what happens when I do this? `num1 = something;` Does the default assignment operator provided by the compiler get called or does a constructor get called? What happens when the constructor is called on an object that already exists? Does that object get "re-constructed"? So what actually happens in that case?

Comment: *This is strange* -- What did you expect to happen?  The code compiled without error, so something was going to happen.  The most logical thing would be that the compiler saw 12.5 and converted it using `Number(double)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know, in the absence of a user provided assignment operator, what happens when I do this `num1 = something;` ?

```
num1 = 12.5;
```

calls implicit `Number::operator =(const Number&)`.

So constructs a temporary number from `double`.

> Does the default assignment operator provided by the compiler get called or does a constructor get called?

Both. Constructor is called for the temporary, not the existing object.

> What happens when the constructor is called on an object that already exists?
>    Does that object get "re-constructed"? So what actually happens in that case?

You cannot recall constructor on existing object. The nearest thing you can do is [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: I had not known about temporary objects before.

Comment: Is that the same thing happening here, `name = "Bjarne";` Is the string literal `"Bjarne"` being converted into temporary `std::string` object and is that object then passed into the `std::string::operator=(const string&)` overloaded assignment operator?

Comment: `std::string` provides special [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) in that case (for performance reasons) to avoid to construct the temporary.

Comment: And so I can also use special overloads for my class to accept `int` and other data types, to avoid constructing the temporary object. I think that it would be a big penalty for large classes with many data members.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jarod42 I'm able to figure it out. So as he suggested, a temporary `Number` object is being invisibly constructed on the right side of `=`, then assignment operator is called, and at the end of that line the temporary object is destroyed.

I added the following code to the `Number` class to actually see what is going on.

```
Number& operator=(const Number& rhs)
{
    cerr << "operator=(const Number&)" << endl;
return *this;
}

~Number() { cerr << "~Number()" << endl; }
```

With this `main()` function

```
int main()
{
    Number num1 = 5;
    num1 = 12.5;

    cout << endl;

    Number num2 = 8;
    num1 = num2;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The following output is produced:

```
Number(5)
Number((float) 12.5)
operator=(const Number&)
~Number()

Number(8)
operator=(const Number&)
~Number()
~Number()
```